# How to assign number for many level subtitles using Loop in Java?

Tags: java, loops

A user can provide a String[] holding title & its level via keyboard. Ex: user can type `History, Level 1` at keyboard level then the system will make up an array `String[] strArray={"History","Level 1"}` & put `strArray` into a `List<String[]>`.

Next, the user can type `History of America, Level 2`, `History of California, Level 3`, etc then the system will add into `List<String[]>` correspondingly.

And then user can print out all the levels & it should show like this:

```
1. History
1.1 History of America
1.1.1 History of California
1.1.2 History of New York
1.2 History of UK
1.3 History of France
2. Economy
.....
```

Note: the user can **arbitrarily** enter any Level they want & the system must check the constraint that the "Level 1 must be at the beginning" & Level must be continuously without omitting 1 level in between, ex "Level 3 must be preceded by Level 2".

Here is my solution but not sure it is the right 1.
-If user insert Level 1, the system will check for the last level 1, if it found nothing, it will add "1." into the `strArray[0]`, ex "1. History". If it found 1, then it increase number by 1, ex "2. Economy".

-If the user insert Level 2, the system will loop backward from the position `size()-1` to 0 of the List. While go backward, if it found Level 2 then it will increase the number by 1 at that level (ex: "1.2 History of UK") & break out of the list. If it did not find Level 2, but found Level 1, then the system check for number & add its number accordingly, ex "1.1 History of America".

If  user insert Level 3, the system will find the Last Level 3 first, then Last Level 2 in the `List`, & add its number accordingly. If Last Level 3 & Last Level 2 not turn up, then the system will generate err saying that user must have Level 2 before inserting Level 3.

I am not sure my solution is the right one. If you think it right can you provide the code, if not, then what is your solution?

Comment: Are all the levels of a level 1 ented before you start entering level 2 values ?

Comment: not necessary, user can enter any level they want, & the system must check for the erorr

Comment: What i meant was, if a user enters the following items-1,1.1,1.1.1,2 and then can he enter another value for 1.1.2 ?

Comment: then the system will put as normal "1. 1", it doesn't care the title name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a possible solution. I didn't use a Map, just a static int array with 100 possible levels. In the main-Method you can find the user input values as expected.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class LevelTest {
    private static final int MAX_LEVEL_COUNT = 100;
    private final int levels[] = new int[MAX_LEVEL_COUNT];
    private int lastLevel = 1;

    public LevelTest() {
        // set all levels to 0
        cleanLevels(0, MAX_LEVEL_COUNT);
    }

    // convert the user input value to level and title (assume, that the input
    // format is "Title, Level XX")
    public void printLevel(final String levelAndTitle) {
        final String[] parts = levelAndTitle.split(", ");
        final int level = Integer.valueOf(parts[1].split(" ")[1]);
        final String title = parts[0];

        printLevel(level, title);
    }

    // prints the level with title to stdout (or an error to stderr if the
    // level is lower than 1 or two level higher than the last level)
    public void printLevel(final int level, final String title) {
        // print error if level is two level higher than last level
        if (level > lastLevel) {
            System.err.println("Level is too high!");
            return;
        }

        // clean all levels after current level, if current level is lower than
        // last level
        if (level < lastLevel) {
            cleanLevels(level, lastLevel);
        }

        // set last level to current level
        lastLevel = level + 1;

        // increment the current level number
        levels[level - 1]++;

        final StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        for (int i = 0; i < level; i++) {
            // concatenate levels
            sb.append(levels[i]).append(".");
        }

        sb.append(" ").append(title);

        // print levels and title
        System.out.println(sb);
    }

    // clean a range of levels by setting each level item to 0
    private void cleanLevels(final int fromLevel, final int toLevel) {
        for (int i = fromLevel; i < toLevel; i++) {
            levels[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final LevelTest lt = new LevelTest();

        final List<String> items = Arrays.asList(new String[] {
            "History, Level 1",
            "History of America, Level 2",
            "History of California, Level 3",
            "History of New York, Level 3",
            "History of UK, Level 2",
            "History of France, Level 2",
            "Economy, Level 1",
        });

        for (final String item : items) {
            lt.printLevel(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: great simple solution, thax you very much

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways you can do it.

Using a Map>,

1. User enters a level 1. You check the entries in your map for keys and if exists, get the largest value and increment it by 1 and add a new entry to the map. If it doesnt exist, create a new entry with 1 as the key.
2. User enters level 2, fetch the highest value of level 1 in the map, fetch its values, and check if the map in the value has any values. If yes, increment the last digit and save it in the map. If not, create a new key and save it in the map.
3. If he enters a level 3, get the largest value of the key from the innner map and check for keys matching the pattern ( eg. 1.1.x).If exists, increment the last value by 1 and save it. If not, create a value and save it.

Similarly you can do it for all levels.